# TestSuite for HttpServlet

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, junit

Today I tried to write my test cases for a HttpServlet. In the web.xml I defined an init parameter with param name and param value. I used JUnit TestCase.

By invoking this line of code:

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
    downloadPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(getInitParameter("downloadPath"));
}
```

and exception will be thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServletConfig has not been initialized
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:185)
at com.example.servlet.DownloadServlet.init(DownloadServlet.java:30)
```

I guess that because the stuff is not running in a web container. To my surprise I was not able to find a test suite which supports HttpServlet. I found StrutsTestCase or ServletTestCase of Apache cactus.

Could I write servlet test cases with this test suite? Can I use Mockito to wrap ServletConfig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll notice the `init()` method is declared in the `GenericServlet` class. It exists so that sub classes override it instead of the `init(ServletConfig)` method.

The Servlet container will invoke the `Servlet#init(ServletConfig)` method (which delegates to `init()` in `HttpServlet` sub classes).

As such, you can mock the `ServletConfig` with your favorite mocking framework (Mockito, EasyMock, etc.) and pass it as an argument to the `init(ServletConfig)` method.